# How to mock navigation.userAgentData.platform with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, navigator

I'm trying to mock navigation.userAgentData.platform for a specific computer type. Let's say the computer I'm testing with is a Windows PC and the computer I want to test for is a macOS. Here is an example of the type of situation...

Code:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (navigator.userAgentData?.platform === 'macOS') {
            return;  
        } else {
            // do something 
        }
    }, []);

    // ...
}
```

How would you go about mocking/duplicating `navigator.userAgentData?.platform` for a unit test?

Usually I would mock with Jest but navigator.userAgentData.platform isn't a function or component I can mock. because it is the computer being used, I assume it will always be the computer I'm using to run the test. I need to specify that a specific computer type is being used for a positive and negative test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good related solution for this case:
https://vincent-benoit.medium.com/how-to-test-useragent-with-jest-inside-a-react-application-cfd87648843a

Basically, mock `userAgentData` in test setup and set as needed within the tests.

Example:

1. In your Jest setup script:

```
    Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'userAgentData', ((value) => ({
        get() { return value; },
        set(v) { value = v; }
    }))(window.navigator.userAgentData));
```

2. In your tests:

```
it('should do something', () => {
    ...setup...
    global.navigator.userAgentData = { platform: 'macOS' };
    ...get result...
    ...assert...
});
```

Comment: This basically ended up being the solve for me but with one minor addition.

In my code itself I never called `window.navigator` but I did need to use it that way when writing the `Object.defineProperty(window.navigator...` but in the assert I wrote it without the "window". 

So, my assert read something like:
`expect(navigator.userAgentData.platform).toBe('macOS');`